# How to upgrade Rails project from Rail 3.0.5 to 3.0.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

This is my first time looking at upgrading a Rails 3.0.5 project to 3.0.6.

It was created using Ruby 1.9.2-p180 and Rails 3.0.5, and now 3.0.6 is out, maybe it is good to upgrade it as well (maybe small incremental upgrade is easier than a bigger upgrade later?).  How would that usually be done?

Answer (score 9):

switch from

> gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

to

> gem 'rails', '3.0.6'

in your `Gemfile`

and then run

`bundle`

Comment: that's it?  how is that usually check against all that is needed or is it based on a "don't worry until problems come up?"  also... you mean `bundle update`?

Comment: I mean `bundle install` which is long form for just `bundle`